# Lake Database converts into a SQL Database in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse

Forgive me I am newbie here and I cannot post images just yet.

Lately I am having few issues with Lake Database that was created in Azure Synapse Analytics using Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse database in PowerApps.

**Dynamics365 developers were adding new columns to Dataverse database and they are not displaying or working when executing queries in SSMS or Synapse Studio.**

Therefore I have unlinked the Synapse Link in PowerApps and relinked with some tables.

When I unlink, the container and Lake database were deleting correctly **but the same database appears in SQL databases section in Azure Synapse studio**. I tried to delete it but I am getting **an error "Operation DROP DATABASE is not allowed for a replicated database"**.

[Before unlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlnsm.png)

[After unlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1naR.png)

**I have created the Lake database again using Synapse link from PowerApps but it seems the tables meta data is not updating.**

Can anyone help me with the above issues (in bold) please.

Answer (score 0):

> an error "Operation DROP DATABASE is not allowed for a replicated database".

This error is returned when you try to create objects in a database that's shared with Spark pool. The databases that are replicated from Apache Spark pools are read only. You can't create new objects into a replicated database by using T-SQL.

Create a separate database and reference the synchronized [tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/metadata/table) by using three-part names and cross-database queries.

> Dynamics365 developers were adding new columns to Dataverse database
> and they are not displaying or working when executing queries in SSMS
> or Synapse Studio.

This issue could be because of many reasons. Without knowing the actual reason, we can't troubleshoot this issue.

If we refer Microsoft official document on [Known limitations and issues with Azure Synapse Link for SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/synapse-link/synapse-link-for-sql-known-issues) if your column data type isn't supported by the Azure Synapse Analytics, it won't be replicated in Azure Synapse Analytics.

Comment: thank you for answer, but I am not creating any objects, I am trying to delete/drop the database. Second I am using the Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse, does these limitations apply the same for Dataverse?

Comment: if possible can you shed any light on the other issue where its converting to SQL Database when I unlink the Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse in PowerApps.

Comment: you need to actually go through the official documents in details to know the actual reason. This might be because of default behavior- of synapse.